# Dragging a TextView into an EditText

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I am new to android programming and I am trying to drag a textview into an edittext.

I have created an OnTouchListener which selects the text in the textview and stores it as ClipData.

**OnTouchListener:**

```
item.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("text", str);
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);

    }
        return true;    
  }

});
```

I want to then append this data onto an EditText view. For this I implemented an OnDragListener for the EditText

**OnDragListener:**

```
    TextStage.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);
                                            CharSequence paste = item.getText();
                                            v.append(paste.toString());                                         
                                            break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED: break;
                default: break;
            }

            return false;
        }

    });
```

**The problem:**

When I complete the drag, two instances of the textview are appended to the edittext.

Example:

**String in TextView:** "I want to drag this"

**After drop in EditText:** "I want to drag this I want to drag this"

I don't see why there should be two drops, as I have overrided onDrag for edittext.
I have also taken care of all the DragEvent actions.

**EDIT:**  After seeing the log, I see this message even after I remove the DragListener

```
11-20 07:30:04.885: I/ViewRootImpl(3518): Reporting drop result: true
```

Any insight into what ViewRootImpl might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that changing the MIME_TYPE of the text to be dropped, from plaintext to html solved the problem as such:

```
ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("text", str);
```

to

```
ClipData data = ClipData.newHtmlText("text", str,"");
```

This way, the edit text viewed the clipdata as html and did not automatically do the drag operation. Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 0):

it happens,because it repeats the drag so you can avoid this like:
Append text like this:

Create boolean variable **isDropping=false;** out of the drag class

When you start drag make `isDropping=true;`

And in Drop:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: 
ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0); 
CharSequence paste = item.getText();
if(isDropping){
v.append(paste.toString());
isDropping=false;
} break;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried this, but it appears there are two separate events happening.

1. OnDrag (where i modify the string)

2. Unknown (text copied exactly as ClipData)

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code and checked it,

I came to know that without implementing Draglistner it is working fine so just remove entire code below from your project it will work fine.

```
 TextStage.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);
                                        CharSequence paste = item.getText();
                                        v.append(paste.toString());                                         
                                        break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED: break;
            default: break;
        }

        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: It works, but I wanted to modify the text on dropping as well. If I just remove the on drag listener, I cannot add the additional functionality. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You missed to return value

```
TextStage.setOnDragListener(new OnDragListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);
                                            CharSequence paste = item.getText();
                                            v.append(paste.toString());                                         
                                            break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED: break;
                default: break;
            }
//return true working perfect
            return true;
        }

    });
```

htmltext work only above 16 API...

Thank you